# How to delete rows that had formulas before value paste?

Tags: vba, excel

I got an spread sheet that include formulas and I wrote a vb code to value paste.

Depending on the input file number of rows that filled is varied and I need to delete the rows those had formulas and now empty. (This is using as connector and otherwise it some how pick these extra rows which is unnecessary)

```
Sheet2.Range("G2:G298").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

Above code not doing anything...

Comment: Problem is all these lines will be at the end of data set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the blanks are results of a formula like:

`=""`

Entered into a cell and then copied and paste as values, those are not really blank cells.
Instead, those are cells that looks blank but contains `zero length` strings.
`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` and even Excel formula `ISBLANK` won't work on it.
One way is to loop through the range and check all that contains `""` and delete it.

```
Dim c As Range, rngtodelete As Range
For Each c In Sheet2.Range("G2:G298")
    If Len(c.Value) = 0 Then
        If rngtodelete Is Nothing Then Set rngtodelete = c _
        Else Set rngtodelete = Union(rngtodelete, c)
    End If
Next
If Not rngtodelete Is Nothing Then rngtodelete.EntireRow.Delete xlUp
```

Another way is using `AutoFilter` like this:

```
Sheet2.Range("G2:G298").AutoFilter 1, "="
Sheet2.Range("G2:G298").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
```

I'm assuming that `G2` does not contain your header but the start of your data.
If it happens to be your header, you'll need to use offset when deleting.

```
Sheet2.Range("G2:G298").Offset(1, 0) _
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
Sheet2.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: Hi, yes these cells created due to ="" part of an equation.

But, I do value paste on Sheet2 all cells first.
That means there are no values in the cells after the value paste.
I try to delete those bank cells created after value paste.

Comment: @Isu As I've said, those are not really considered blank. Above suggested solutions will work for you.

Comment: Thx a lot for your time and effort... Seems like it some how pick those cells again and again in connector...

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working either...

I can't figure out the logic of not considering it as a blank cell once value paste is zero...

Comment: actually your code working perfectly.
I mistakenly thought I got data only in the first 298 lines...
When I increase that to 1000 it delete lines perfectly....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by *"This is using as connector"*, but I believe it has to do with an export/import process to another application.

As mentioned, a *zero length string* is not the same as a truly blank cell. However, you can rid your worksheet of them easily. The fastest method I am aware of is a quick cyclic run through all of the columns, applying Text-to-Columns ► Fixed width ► Finish to each.

When that is done, the zero length strings will be reverted to truly blank cells but the worksheet's used range will still overlap those empty cells found at the bottom of the dataset. This means that any export to an external program will try to export those cells. Just run `.UsedRange` to get Excel to reevaluate the actual used range.

First, tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to see what Excel *thinks* is the last used cell on the worksheet. Next, run the following macro.

```
Sub prep_for_export()
    Dim c As Long
    Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address(0, 0)
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For c = 1 To .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, c), _
              DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
        Next c
    End With
    Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    Debug.Print Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Edit *Sheet1* in all four places if you have to before running it.

That is a little homogeneous but I think it should work for your purposes. After running the macro, tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> back at your worksheet again to see what Excel thinks is the last used cell on your worksheet. The before and after range addresses were recorded to the VBE's *Immediate* window as well.

Comment: Shows error             
    .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, c), _
                      DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)

Comment: The code ran on my sample workbook. I would suppose that you are going to have to provide some redacted data in order that I might have a chance at figuring out why your situation is different. It sounds like you have blank columns.

Comment: Thx for letting me know the short cut Ctrl + End...
As I mentioned, I found error when run that code...
Previous code from L42 now working ok...
Thx