# Faster row delelete method

Tags: vba, excel

There are 15 csv files. Each file has 8000 rows. In all files, column A contains either numerics or "Delete". Rows with the value "Delete" must be deleted. The following is more than slow. It's meaningless. Any other Suggestion?

```
 For j = lastRow To 1 Step -1
     If Wb1.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 1).Value = "Delete" Then
        Wb1.Worksheets(1).Rows(j).Delete
        lastRow = Wb1.Worksheets(1).Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End If
 Next j
```

Comment: This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17637270/5722505

Comment: How about sorting on column A first and then deleting  the block of rows that are `delete`?

Comment: if rows are sorted, so 'delete' rows are at the bottom of your data you can  clear them instead of deleting. This may speed things up.

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I ll let you know

Comment: Try implementing deleting in on go either by [looping or filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28685979/2685412)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Performance - 1 million rows - Delete rows containing a value, in less than 1 min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959315/excel-vba-performance-1-million-rows-delete-rows-containing-a-value-in-less)

Comment: Why not use pandas or R as your skill tags indicate? Each can easily import CSVs and delete rows!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked properly (5 mins for 15 csv of 9000 rows each)

```
For j = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        ValueToFind = "Delete" 'look at this value
        With Wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A or whatever column
             Set Rng = .Find(What:=ValueToFind, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

             If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                GoTo Next_Row 'value found
             Else
                Wb.Worksheets(1).Rows(j).Delete       
             End If
        End With
Next_Row:     
Next j
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete(xlShiftUp)
```

Or...
Use SpecialCells to delete only the rows that are visible after autofiltering:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```